# Python Eventlet spawn not working

Tags: python, eventlet

```
import eventlet

def foo():
    print('foo')

def main():
    eventlet.monkey_patch()
    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
    pool.spawn(foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Expectation:

> foo

But nothing happens, no print's. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait the spawned thread to finish, using [`eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread.wait`](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/greenthread.html#eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread.wait):

```
thread = pool.spawn(foo)
thread.wait()
```

or using [`eventlet.greenpool.GreenPool.waitall`](http://eventlet.net/doc/modules/greenpool.html#eventlet.greenpool.GreenPool.waitall):

```
pool.spawn(foo)
pool.waitall()
```